# How to highlight a link clicked?

Tags: jquery

If I have 3 links:

```
<a href="#link1">Somelink</a>
<a href="#link2">Somelink 2</a>
<a href="#link3">Somelink 3</a>
```

I want to be able to make it so that when clicking on Somelink 2, it will make the link bold. If the user clicks on "Somelink", then that link becomes bold, and the others do not become bold. (Same if Somelink 3 is clicked). How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="mylinks">
  <a href="#link1">Somelink</a>
  <a href="#link2">Somelink 2</a>
  <a href="#link3">Somelink 3</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight{     
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#mylinks a').click(function(){
 $('#mylinks a').removeClass('highlight');
 $(this).addClass('highlight');
});

});
```

Comment: The CSS for the `highlight` class should be `font-weight:bold` to suit the question, but +1 as I'm being pedantic and this is the answer I would have given :)

Comment: instead of assigning classes all over the DOM isn't easier to just target a parent element?

Answer (score 5):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/udulon/1/edit)*

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();         // prevent default anchor behav.
   $(this).css({ fontWeight: 'bold' }).siblings().css({ fontWeight:'normal' });
});
```

on `click` change the font style and targeting siblings of `this` with the method `.siblings()` you make sure to reset all adiacent `<a>` elements.

No need to mention that the code above will target all `a` elements, it's just for example. 
Instead use a parent element as selector like in the demo:

```
$('#myLinks a').click(function(e){
```

Answer (score 1):

Following solution is without JavasSript.

**HTML code:**

```
    <ul class="listNone">
                        <li class="inline">
                            <button name="planText2" type="button">The Studio</button> &nbsp;
                        </li>
                        <li class="inline">
                            <u> <button autofocus name="planText2" type="button">Deluxe Portion</button></u> &nbsp;
                        </li>
                        <li class="inline">
                            <button name="planText2" type="button">Penthouse</button> &nbsp;
                        </li>
                        <li class="inline">
                            <button name="planText2" type="button" >Top Garden</button> &nbsp;
                        </li>
                        <li style="display:inline">
                            <button name="planText2" type="button">Double Height</button> &nbsp;
                        </li>
                        <!--onclick="this.style.color='#3399ff';this.style['text-decoration']='underline'"-->
<!--onclick="window.location.href='about.html'"-->
                    </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
    button[name="planText2"]{
        background: none; color: #5b5f66; border: none; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font: inherit; cursor: pointer; outline: inherit;
    }
    button[name="planText2"]:visited {
        color: #3399ff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    button[name="planText2"]:focus {
        color: #3399ff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    button[name="planText2"]:active {
        color: #3399ff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">some link 1</a>
<br>
<a href="#">some link 2</a>
<br>
<a href="#">some link 3</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('a').click(function() { $(this).css({'font-weight':'bold'}) })
```